# html validation in mat-select required is not working

Tags: angular, select, angular-material

I need to required set mat-select in my project but the validation is not triggering

I have tried HTML validation using  #countryId="ngModel" and requred= true

```
<form #f="ngForm" (submit)="f.valid && updateData() ">
 <mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Country" [(ngModel)]="userDetails.countryId" name="dddd" #select="ngModel"
    (change)="onCountryChange()" required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countryList" [value]="country.id"> {{country.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="f.submitted && select.invalid">
    <mat-error *ngIf="select.errors.required">Country is required</mat-error>
  </mat-error>
 </mat-form-field>
 <button mat-button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I didn't find any error message or the validation from this code

output of {{f | json}}

```
{ "submitted": false, "_directives": [], "ngSubmit": { "_isScalar": false, "observers": [], "closed": false, "isStopped": false, "hasError": false, "thrownError": null, "__isAsync": false }, "form": { "validator": null, "asyncValidator": null, "pristine": true, "touched": false, "_onDisabledChange": [], "controls": {}, "valueChanges": { "_isScalar": false, "observers": [], "closed": false, "isStopped": false, "hasError": false, "thrownError": null, "__isAsync": false }, "statusChanges": { "_isScalar": false, "observers": [], "closed": false, "isStopped": false, "hasError": false, "thrownError": null, "__isAsync": false }, "status": "VALID", "value": {}, "errors": null } }
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njy6f1-8bwrah?file=app/select-hint-error-example.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
  <mat-error *ngIf="select.errors?.required">
    Country is required
  </mat-error>
```

or

```
  <mat-error *ngIf="select.hasError('required')">
    Country is required
  </mat-error>
```

**Updated**

```
  <mat-error *ngIf="select.hasError('required') || (f.submitted && select.invalid)">
      Please choose an animal
  </mat-error>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njy6f1)

Comment: @PaulCheriyan check I have add a demo

Comment: I have seen. it is working in click....but it is not working in submit. I have added my requirement in demo...and thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the filter when you display the error:

```
*ngIf="f.submitted && select.invalid"
```

Remove the f.submitted from the ngIf.

Tip: to see the state of your form to debug issues emmit it using {{f | json}}.
That will display all the state on the form.

Comment: ok the form is Valid, in your case. so you dont have validation error, and that is because  [(ngModel)]="userDetails.countryId" countryId is not null.

Answer (score 0):

have a look here [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dllgup)

.html

```
  <form #countryForm="ngForm">
    <br>
      <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="Select Country" name="select" [(ngModel)]="select" required>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let coutry of Countries" [value]="coutry.viewValue" >
          {{ coutry.viewValue }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error *ngIf="countryForm.invalid">Country is required</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <div>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>

    </form>
```

.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  select;
  Countries = [
    { viewValue: 'USA'},
    { viewValue: 'UK'},
    { viewValue: 'UAE'}
  ];

}
```

Comment: thanks, @Mahruj it is working in submit. how could I add other input fields in this demo

Comment: in updated code how could I validate comment field ...u have checked the error using the mat form object, not the model object.